# best way to find substring of integer number in perl

Tags: perl, string

I have a string like

```
$number="1234567";
```

and i want to extract substring out of it , but i am not getting proper results with `substr` function.

If i execute

```
substr $number ,0,1 ;
```

i get `1` as output but it should be `12`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `12`, you need:

```
substr $number, 0, 2
```

The syntax for `substr` is:

```
substr $var, OFFSET, LENGTH
```

So when you do:

```
substr $number ,0,1
```

the `OFFSET` will be `0` and `LENGTH` will be `1`.

`perl` is zero-indexed i.e. the indexing starts at `0`, and the length of the substring you have picked is `1`, so you would only get `1` in the output expectedly.